# Image is different size to the others?

Tags: html, css

I have this issue where the second image is slightly smaller then it's counter parts, even though all the attributes (as far as I can tell) are exactly the same?

http://staging-triteamglos.transitiongraphics.co.uk/

Members sections, three circular images, the middle one isa different size?

```css
/*--- Member Benifits
--------------------------------------------*/

.header-white {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.par-white {
  text-align: center;
}
p.upper {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
}
.mymember1 {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.mymember1 img,
.mymember2 img,
.mymember3 img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
.mymember2 {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.mymember3 {
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  width: 33.3%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0!important;
}
.member {
  margin: 15px auto!important;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="header-white">Member Benefits</h1>

<p class="par-white">Thinking of joining TTG? Have a look at some of the member benefits below</p>

<div class="mymember1">
  <p>
    <a href="/membership/">
      <img src="http://staging-triteamglos.transitiongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/member-swimmer.jpg" height="185">
    </a>
  </p>
  <p class="upper">Advice from experienced triathletes</p>
  <p class="my_content">Our club benefits from a membership of very experience triathletes who have competed across all variations of the sport and they are more then to share their experiences.</p>
</div>

<div class="mymember2">
  <p>
    <a href="/membership/">
      <img src="http://staging-triteamglos.transitiongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/member-cyclist.jpg" height="185">
    </a>
  </p>
  <p class="upper">Opportunity to train with others</p>
  <p class="my_content">Motivation is key in training, training with others will help you achieve your goals what ever they are.</p>
</div>

<div class="mymember3">
  <p>
    <a href="/membership/">
      <img src="http://staging-triteamglos.transitiongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/member-runner.jpg" height="185">
    </a>
  </p>
  <p class="upper">Comradeship from a big team</p>
  <p class="my_content">We all want to achieve our personally goals, however when your surrounded by friends with the same mindset, the goals soon become secondary.</p>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="container member">
  <a class="btn" href="#">FIND OUT MORE</a>
</div>
```

Comment: For one thing...the images aren't circular in your demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.mymember1 img, .mymember2 img, .mymember3 img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you were using padding from both sides in **mymember2** class. That's why its creating the problem. Also the above code fine and define the  width and 
height for all the images.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your second **image size is 180x180** while the other two were **187x187**. they wont have the same size because your using border radius 50% on all of them.

To solve. its either u set a same sizes for the images or fixed ur 2nd image size to 187x187, or the 1st and 3rd img to 180x180 to make them all the same.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the 2nd image is smaller is because in its parent div, mymember2 was given an extra 15px padding.

I suggest you change all padding css for your .mymember# classes to margins and decrease their width to fit the page.

also, I would suggest putting all common css in 1 class called memember

```
.mymember {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 31%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 15px;
}
```

And for every specific css give it to the corresponding div

Comment: I recommend you to use the developer tools of your browser to adjust to the right margins and content width